# Database Migration with the flyway or dbup(.net library/dbup extension) with PostgreSQL

Tags: database, postgresql, flyway, sql-scripts, dbup

First of all, I am sorry because it might be a stupid question but after a day research I am confused and I have a very less time to decide.

We are using TFS as a CI tool and as an SCM. And Postgresql for DB.
Planning to Automate DB with Postgresql and TFS.

Please suggest a tool for this that I can go forward with running my SQL files on specific DB as I want.

Can anyone please tell me if I use DbUp Migration Extension of TFS is it supporting Postgresql? As [this link](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=johanclasson.UpdateDatabaseWithDbUp) shows it only works with Microsoft SQL Server or Microsoft SQL Azure and then another [Document](https://dbup.readthedocs.io/en/latest/supported-databases/) says DbUp supports a number of different databases including Postgresql.

also, Does Flyway have support for c# and TFS ?

Comment: We use http://liquibase.org/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Database sync or migration tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13775160/database-sync-or-migration-tool)

Comment: Asking for tools is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Likely [asked and answered already on the sister site Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=site%3Asoftwarerecs.stackexchange.com+database+migration&t=osx&ia=web). Tip: “database migration” is the emerging term for what you seem to be asking. See also [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schema_migration).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most popular tools to do what you want is [Liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/) and [Flyway](https://flywaydb.org/).

As I know there is only one significant difference: Flyway - plain SQL based, Liquibase - provides abstraction level based on XML, JSON or YAML as well as plain SQL. You can use abstractions (provided by Liquibase) to increase portability of your scripts.

Comment: Liquibase supports [plain SQL scripts](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/sql_format.html) as well. Although I prefer Liquibase especially _because_ of the DBMS independent XML format.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name This is what I wanted to say. I would recommend `Liquidbase` if you want something based on abstraction to increase portability.

Comment: But "the principal difference" isn't a difference as Liquibase supports plain SQL scripts as well. _If_ you want to point out a difference then it's that Liquibase supports plain SQL scripts as Flyway does plus DBMS independent alternatives

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name does it better now?